# How to use double checked lock to init a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, locking, shared-ptr, lazy-initialization

(Assuming VC++ 2010: (1) can use /volatile:ms, (2) no std::atomic yet, (3) no thread-safe static variable initialization, (4) no std::call_once)

If I have a plain C pointer, I can impl the following double checked lock pattern to avoid the cost of lock every time:

```
static volatile void * ptr = nullptr;

//...
if ( ptr == nullptr)
{
   // Acquire Lock
   if (ptr == nullptr)
   {
      // some code
      // ptr = ...; // init ptr
   }
   // Release Lock
}
// ....
```

Since VC++ 2005, the volatile makes sure the above code is correct. Assume I'm OK with the code being not portable.

Now assume I need to replace the plain pointer with a std::shared_ptr or boost::shared_ptr, how would I do the same thing? How to make that shared_ptr volatile? Do I need another volatile flag?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Double-checked locking is bad.

Comment: What makes you believe that `volatile` makes that code correct?

Comment: If you change `static volatile void *ptr = nullptr;` to `std::atomic<void*> ptr = nullptr;` the double-checked locking will work. This assumes C++11.

Comment: @Daniel : `volatile` guarantees a memory barrier in VC++ 2005+. Hence "*Since VC++ 2005, the volatile makes sure the above code is correct.*" ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn Ah, thanks. (Supposing that _is_ actually what made the OP believe the code is correct, since that makes sense.)

Comment: yes, I do assume /volatile:ms with VC++. (Thus the code is not portable or even correct in standard C++). Sorry for not making it clear. My question should be how to do the same thing with the std::shared_ptr or boost::shared_ptr in VS2010 (where std::atomic is not yet available.)

Answer (score 4):

With C++11, there are atomic accessor functions for `shared_ptr`. To write a double-checked lock that uses `shared_ptr`, use those accessors:

```
static std::shared_ptr<MyType> ptr;
if (std::atomic_load(ptr) == 0) {
    // lock the lock
    if (std::atomic_load(ptr) == 0) {
        std::shared_ptr<MyType> local_ptr(new MyType);
        std::atomic_store(ptr, local_ptr);
    }
    // unlock the lock
}
return ptr;
```

Comment: std::atomic would be ideal. Unfortunately, I need to use VS2010.

Answer (score 3):

> Since VC++ 2005, the volatile makes sure the above code is correct.

No, it does not. `volatile` has nothing to do with threading or atomicity.

Your current code is incorrect and is not guaranteed by any C++ standard to produce reasonable behavior.

Since your pretend-locking code doesn't work in general, it's certainly not going to work on `shared_ptr` or other smart pointers. If you want cheaper locking, look into lock-free coding patterns.

Comment: In _Visual C++_, which the OP specifically mentions, `volatile` guarantees a full memory fence. If the question is about standard C++, you're entirely correct, but I don't get the impression that that's what the question is about.

Comment: Yes. I should be clear that it's about VC++ specific code (using /volatile:ms). Thus the above code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ 2011 it isn't even necesary to use **any** explict synchronization. According to 6.7 [stmt.dcl] paragraph 4 the initialization is synchronized by the system:

> If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.

This seems to imply that the `std::shared_ptr<T>` can be initialzed like this:

```
{
    static std::shared_ptr<MyType> ptr(new MyType(/*...*/));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, AFAIK, this feature is not even in VC2012 (please correct me if I'm wrong). Also, (1) does it use lazy initialization? (2) if I need to have some costly logic in the "//some code" part before calling the ctor, it's still not ideal.

Comment: It is lazy initialization and you'll need to do the costly initialization at some point anyway. You can call a function returning a `std::shared_ptr<MyType>` if the initialization doesn't fit a constructor. The implementstion will apply something like `std::call_once()` to make sure threads are correctly blocked during initialization and minimally impeded afterwards. I don't know if any compiler implements this feature, yet. I still consider it useful to point out how it is correctly done.

Comment: @LostInTranslation : You're correct re: VC++ 2012 -- according to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) N2660 is not implemented.